# MODIS L1B reprojection and mosaic problem

Tags: modis, envi, image-mosaic, modis-reprojection-tool

I have been using MODIS L1B file to retrieve water vapor content. However, my study area is exactly between the gap between two images,just like this:

[image]

I have tries ENVI MCTK extensions, HEG TOOLS, MRTSwath, etc. And I also used MOD03 file for precise reprojection. However, the gap cannot be eliminated.

Does anyone know a solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: Can you try the imagery from a previous orbit?

Comment: @AndreJ, I need two images from the same day, so that I can retrieve water vapor content at the same time and same place.

Answer (score 1):

MODIS L1B data are SWATH format and unfortunately for some dates there is gaps like this. as you see nasa world view website, this problem generally happened in MODIS swath data.